# HandsOnTable editor custom function

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, handsontable

I'm using the autocomplete editor of HOT, but needed to have my own template of the  option-list. I've been able to accomplish that, by removing the default display and replacing it with my own while doing a lazy load of its content. But I need to perform specific tasks on each of the options being clicked.

The issue is that I cannot find a way to have my `<a ng-click='doSomething()'>` or `<a onclick = 'doSomething()'>` tags to find my `"doSomething"` function.

I've tried the extend prototype of the autocomplete instance, have put my function out there on my controller to no avail. Is there any way I can insert a delegate function inside this editor that could be triggered from inside my custom-made template? (Using angularjs, HOT version 0.34)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I actually needed actions specific to each area being clicked. What I did to make it work was this: while inserting the items for the list, I created the element and bound it to the function right away: l`iElement = document.createElement('li') .... liElement.onclick = doSomething(){}` .... got it working this way ..

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown options cannot interpret HTML instead of Headers.

To perform action when an option is selected you can use Handsontable callback : AfterChange or BeforeChange 
Here you can find all HOT callbacks https://docs.handsontable.com/0.34.0/tutorial-using-callbacks.html

This JSFiddle can help you http://jsfiddle.net/fsvakoLa/

```
beforeChange: function(source, changes){
    console.log(source, changes)
},
 afterChange: function(source, changes){
    console.log(source, changes);
  if(!source) return;
   if(source[0][1] == 0){//if ocurs on col 0
        let newsource = optionsWBS[source[0][3]];
        cols[1] = {
                                type : 'dropdown',
                            source: newsource,
                        strict: false
                            };
      hot.updateSettings({columns: cols});
      hot.render();
  };
}
```